# VLC media player not working : Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, vlc

I tried everything for 4 days.

VLC media player looks funny with no menu buttons. I've tried to install it with snap, ppa, version 3.0 version 4.0 but nothing works.

I want to play DVD the matrix with external LG DVD drive. I installed `libdvd`, even installed with synaptic; nothing works, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't want to do it,but i solved the problem by downloading wine and its front-end interface which allowed me to download vlc 2 and I watched Matrix with no problems. Until I can find a fix for vlc 3.0 4.0 this will have to be a workaround

Answer (score -1):

I had days ago same problem like you and below are the steps I used to solve it:

1- Uninstall the snapd that came by default with Ubuntu 18:

`sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`

2- Reinstall it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

3- Install VLC:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

4- Launch VLC for the first time via terminal by typing:
`vlc`

Works well for others packages also.
Regards!

Comment: vlc launches but when i push play the open media window is blank still